# Unit testing Javascript (frontend), when the backend renders the HTML

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

So.. We have a Java backend, that renders some templates trough JSP.

Then we have a Javascript Framework, that basically just goes 'on top' of the received HTML.. It doesn't 'ask' for anything from the server (mostly).. The html has a data-component="component" attribute, and that 'triggers' a Javascript component to load..

In my understanding, we have only one options concerning testing and thats Selenium with end to end tests, because the html is required for the Javascript, and the server can change that HTML on the go..

But, we could after some work, make a 'static html' backup (every 5 minutes or so) of every page and let our unit tests run on top of that.

So my question is: is that a 'best practice' in this kind of situation? Or would you normally solve this another way?

Comment: if you're unit testing your js business logic i would try to separate it from the dom as much as possible. you can use mocha or whatever for that.

Comment: Thats the problem, its one of these damn e-commerce websites, where Javascript has almost no proper business-logic but only 'UI' related things.. Thus we need the complete HTML/CSS for every test

Comment: if you have a set number of html pages to be rendered you could save each of those html files as fixtures and use qunit to test directly "on the page". a lot easier to setup than selenium

Comment: Yes thats my proposal, but the question is: is it best practice to backup the 'final' rendered HTML every 5 minutes for that?